# getDisplayValue() and getValue() from a cell returns #VALUE! error most of the time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy-paste, valueerror, getvalue

I have modified a script of a punch in/out system by adding a function that grabs a value from AQ1 cell in Schedule_data sheet and places it in E column of Break_data sheet to last empty row along with other data in separate cells.
The problem I'm encountering is that sometimes the cell content are copied over, and sometimes I get #VALUE! error instead. I've tried removing the formula from the referenced cell and only leaving plain text, but got same result. Changing getValue() to getDisplayValue() also hasn't changed the outcome. Clearing the logger after if/else statements hasn't helped either. The error seems to come up without any pattern. The original script still works fine and consistently produces the data in their respective A,B,C,D columns, but I'm afraid I don't know enough about apps script to effectively troubleshoot it.

This is what I have so far:

```
function cellRange(value) {
return 
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Schedule_data').getRange(value).getDisplayValue();
}
function setValue(cellName, value) {
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Break_data').getRange(cellName).setValue(value);
}
function getValue(cellName) {
return 
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Break_data').getRange(cellName).getValue();
}
function getNextRow() {
return SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Break_data').getLastRow() + 1;
}
function addRecord(a, b, c, d, e) {
  var row = getNextRow();
  setValue('A' + row, a);
  setValue('B' + row, b);
  setValue('C' + row, c);
  setValue('D' + row, d);
  setValue('E' + row, e);
}

function pause() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Break_data');
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var setColumn = 2;
var inORout = sheet.getRange(lastRow, setColumn).getValue();
Logger.log(inORout);

  if(inORout == 'Pause'){
    return;
  }
  else
   var formatDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "h:mma");
   var fullDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yy");
   setValue('d1', Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "EEEE"));
   addRecord(getValue('d1'),'Pause',  formatDate, fullDate, cellRange('aq1'));
}

function resume() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Break_data');
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var setColumn = 2;
var inORout = sheet.getRange(lastRow, setColumn).getValue();
Logger.log(inORout);

  if(inORout == 'Resume'){
    return;
  }
  else
   var formatDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "h:mma");
   var fullDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yy");
   setValue('d1', Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "EEEE"));
   addRecord(getValue('d1'),'Resume',  formatDate, fullDate, cellRange('aq1'));
}
```

[image of value error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgx0p.jpg)

Despite of how it looks in the attached image, the added E column is not associated with the current day of the week or relevant to the A column, but instead displays the starting day of a project which sometimes may last longer than a day.

Answer (score 0):

#### Pause or Remove

I think it could work for you this way:

```
function pauseOrResume(pr='Pause') {
  const opts = ['Pause','Resume'];
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ash = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Break_data')
  const sdsh = ss.getSheetByName('Schedule_data');
  const inORout = sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow(), 2).getDisplayValue();
  if (inOrout == pr) {
    return;
  } else {
    const formatDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "h:mma");
    const fullDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yy");
    sh.getRange('D1').setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "EEEE"));
    ash.appendRow([sh.getRange('D1').getDisplayValue(), pr , formatDate, fullDate, sdsh.getRange('aq1').getDisplayValue()])
  }
}
```

Attach these helper functions to your buttons or use side bar button and we can pass parameters with them.  Either way is okay. Personally I don't like buttons on sheets but that's just me.

I changed all getValue() and getValues() to displayValue/s();

```
function pause() {
  pauseOrResume();
}

function resume() {
  pauseOrResume('Resume')
}
```

Comment: We will need some data in order to isolate the problem.

Comment: thanks! I have tried your version and this came up: Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getSelection.

Comment: Oh that's was an error on my part.  They were changing the software in the editor yesterday a little and it was behaving differently.  That should have been getSheetByName() but when I first saw you code I new it could be all done in one piece.  It may not work at first but if we work together I'm sure we can get it to work for you if you can explain what you are attempt to do.

Comment: Maybe some more context would help - Pause and Resume functions are tied to two buttons on another sheet. When Pause button is pressed, the code looks at column B to check that the last row does not contain "pause" text. If it doesn't, then it places "pause" in a new row. The same thing for Resume button. Another sheet then looks at the time difference between pause and resume and adds that to a scheduled through some formulas. It doesn't necessarily have to be 2 separate buttons, I just don't know how to modify everything to only have 1 pause/resume button.

Comment: I'll be back shortly I just got up

Comment: Take your time, I'm not in a rush. Timeframe is not as much of a factor in my project as making sure everything works well.

Comment: Are you okay with using the sidebar for the buttons? Which another way of saying are you limited in space for the sidebar

Comment: Your code is much better but unfortunately it produced the same result as the original code with intermittent value errors. I wasn't aware formulas able to impede the code from copying a cell value, because after deleting a range with time driven formulas the AQ1 cell was able to be copied every time. Is there any way around this flaw? I will continue narrowing down the range. Also I would rather not add the sidebar because of the way the user interface is set up. It would actually have been nice if google sheets gave an option to hide row count and column labels to create a minimal look.

Comment: Well lets work together to fix it.

Comment: I don't really understand your last comment.  Could you repeat that again with more detail.  Also be aware that I don't use formulas very much any more.

Comment: There is a range of cells with a bunch of formulas which are updated every minute because they drive visual timers. Once I removed that range of cells your code stated working flawlessly. So I'm wondering why would formulas impede a code from completing successfully. Later today I will try to see if it's because the worksheet is set up to update calculations every minute. Is there another way of isolating a given cell to copy it's content? Because it just seems like AppsScript is trying to copy some other properties of AQ1 cell and not just what is displayed in it.

Comment: Do you have any array formulas that essentially intersect all rows?

Comment: No array formulas in the sheet tab where the referenced AQ1 cell is located. I narrowed the error down to a range of cells that pull time data from another tab (which also doesn't have any array formulas).

Comment: I guess I can't help you.  Sorry.  It's another reason for me to continue to avoid the use of cell formulas.

Comment: Just a thought: is there a way to first check if the cell contains actual value before copying its contents? Or checking if it has text inside matching [mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, sun] values?

Comment: Of course you can see if a cell have value with getValue()

Comment: Is it possible to hold AQ1 value in a log for a couple of hours and pull data from the log instead of the cell?

Comment: Well at this point I'm depending upon you to figure it out because the only thing I've done so far is to reorganize you code because of the similarities that I have seen in it.  But in reality I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish.  So if you want my help you going to have figure out a way to explain what your trying to do in images and simple word because number one I will not follow links to your spreadsheet and I don't know much about formulas because I hate to use them because I find that people that do often can't explain what they have done

Comment: Well so far you have only rewrote the original code without addressing this post's original question regarding the value error, or have yet to offer any suggestion on possible ways to mitigate the issue. I offered a possible workaround by first checking if the cell value matches a text string before actually copying its content over to another sheet. Holding the value in a log file and pulling data from there might also have been worth trying. I only meant to help you, but judging from frustration in your response it seems this isn't possible to accomplish. I appreciate your effort anyway.

Comment: Those are all design issues.  Our scope is primarily scripting questions.  I simplified you code and provide you an alternative technique for attaching to buttons.  When you figure out how you wish to proceed we will be here to assist you with scripting issues.  So I guess of work here is done for now.